# Library project API version effects on main application compatibility or not?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

For example I have main application with `targetSdkVersion=18` and Android library project with `targetSdkVersion=14`. Build targets (Eclipse project's setting) are also 18 and 14. Will this difference effect on my applications compatibility or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no this will not effect any this.you can always change the compatibility by changing the android support library of the project